# how to define the IP address using classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I just need a fully code how to get/define the IP address for every time user login into my website because i need to save the IP address into the database table for keep track where the IP comes. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You're better off calling a simple function like this:

```
Function IP()
    Dim strIP : strIP = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") 
    If strIP = "" Then strIP = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
    IP = strIP
End Function
```

This will return the true IP address of the user, even if they're behind a proxy or being served through a CDN which can sometimes cause an issue.

Comment: I've try but I only get 127.0.0.1. how to get the correct ip for this function..?

Comment: This is perhaps you're running the script locally. Once the script is sitting on a server on the internet and not on your local network then it should return the correct IP.

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.Write Request.ServerVariables ("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

See more at http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

You even could get such information: does user using proxy server, and what his real IP address (beyond proxy).

See sample: http://1click.lv/debug/debug.asp
;)

Answer (score 0):

use the Request.Servervariables Collection.

ip would be the following:

```
Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for a list of iis Server variables