# asp classic get user IP When login

Tags: asp-classic

We have a staff attendance system. It's written in asp classic with MS ACCESS database where its store users info and their login time.

I want to add one more extra thing, where I can see the users workstation IP address from where they login.

We believe that some one is logging in for some one else even they are not in office.

How to get the workstation IP address?

we have around 25 client in a user network. when ever they reach the office the have to login to LoginStaff Attendance System, [Attendance login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b46WC.png)

when ever the user login its write in MS Access database as below.[Staff Attendance Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeazq.png)

we think someone is attending attendance for someone before he even arrive into office to show he was on Time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the public IP address of a user in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285957/how-to-get-the-public-ip-address-of-a-user-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Please see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285957/how-to-get-the-public-ip-address-of-a-user-in-c-sharp

Comment: Dear im noob in this thing and i don`t know how it works. i have MS ACCESS database linked to this system where the worker check in time recorded, i want to add a extra filed to get the each user IP, maybe 2 workers login from same machine

Comment: You're asking your question with tags c# and asp.net, but your screenshot clearly shows an .asp extension. Is it possible you're working with asp-classic and vbscript? Then you might consider duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131587/how-to-define-the-ip-address-using-classic-asp

Comment: Dear as i said im noob in this thing i don`t know where to put the codes and how it will be write in Access

Comment: you could get even real IP address, if user using some proxy server which are completly hide real IP address

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

To get the remote ip address

Answer (score 0):

If the site is CloudFront'ed, you have to use Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR") instead ...